# Instantiate WriteableImage in Background Task

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I am writing a Windows 8 Store App with Live Tiles. Every live tile is an image that needs to be refreshed every *x* minutes. I am using a Background Task with a time trigger to generate my image and refresh the tile.

Generating my image implies creating a new one and paint my stuff on it but for some reason I am getting an exception when trying to create a new instance of WriteableBitmap:

```
var newImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap(10, 10);
```

or

> var newImage = BitmapFactory.New(10, 10);

throws this exception:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a
>   different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E
>   (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

I have an impression this is because there is no UI thread in the Background Task but then again, why would the WriteableBitmap require an UI thread?

Any idea how to workaround this? How would I instantiate the WriteableBitmap in my background task?

Comment: Good question. I would love to see an answer that actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was not possible in Windows 8.

It was made possible in subsequent versions Win 8.1 and then UWP via the [XamlBackgroundTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Dispatcher`

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new Action(() => createBitmap)
);
```

**UPDATE**

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync
    (CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
    () => new WriteableBitmap(10, 10));
```

Comment: This would probably work in a regular Application, but because this is a WinRT Background Task, there is no Application.Current.Dispacher available. Do you have a working code snippet to be placed in the context of a background task in WinRT?

Comment: @Mayank that code does not work either. Dispatcher refers to either ServiceModel.Dispatcher, which does not have a RunAsync method, or the standard application Dispatcher. I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

You still can use the following code:

```
 CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
            () =>{
                // Your UI update code goes here!
                WriteableBitmap writeableBmp = BitmapFactory.New(imageWidth, imageHeight);
            });
```

But most probably you will get another exception (InvalidOperationException) saying:
A method was called at an unexpected time. WinRT information: Could not create a new view because the main window has not yet been created.